# How can I set up my program to hand an object to the correct class?

Tags: c#, ninject

I don't know if this is something that can be handled by a DI since I am still wrapping my head around using a DI.

**Project:**
I have an object of ISettings that I want to hand off to a ISettingsVerification class.  However, I have a number of different classes that inherit from ISettingsVerification.  These classes all handle the ISettings object differently based on a particular property (IisVersion).

**Question:**
How can I set it up so that in the main program, I don't worry about which ISettingsVerification class gets the ISettings Object, that my program will handle that logic.  I am familiar with using the DI Ninject, would this be something that I could do there, or am I going to have to use something like a Switch statement to make that determination?

I like the idea of extracting this logic from the heart of my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to write a switch statement *somewhere*. But of course it doesn't have to be in the "heart of the application".

One solution would be to use some kind of factory:

```
public class SettingsVerificationFactory : ISettingsVerificationFactory
{
    public ISettingsVerification Create(Version iisVersion)
    {
        switch (iisVersion)
        {
            case 6:
                return new Iis6SettingsVerification();
            case 7:
                return new Iis7SettingsVerification();
            // etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use that factory (through injection or directly) when you need a verifier for a settings object.

Comment: @rmac:  Thanks, thats what I kept coming to.  A follow up question I have for you is:  Since I am going to be most likely generating different ISettings objects determined by the OS/IIS versions I am working with - and this object is passed into the SettingsVerificationFactory, Would it be better to either A) submit the ISettings object to the correct ISettingsVerification class based on the either a property in the ISettings object (i.e. IisVersion) or the typeof class (i.e. Iis6Settings)  OR

Comment: B) have the IVerificationFactory "assume" it was passed the correct ISettings object and let the IVerificationFactory check for the local IIS version and on its results pass the ISettings object to the proper VerificationSettings object?

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from this info, but if you have already determined and stored the IIS version, why not reuse that value.

Comment: I wonder though, why are you shuffling around an ISettings object that isn't "verified"? Does that mean it isn't valid? Generally I would recommend validating objects at the point of creation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I am not sure i understand your question, the part of my project that does the verification is the part that was discussed in my example.  This verification class takes the settings and determines if the actions that are going to be carried out on the settings is possible (i.e. does the website name already exists?).   The settings class is already instantiated based on the IIS settings version that is found on the system and that is handed to the main program at initializing.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the details of your system so I'm just guessing. It sounded like a situation where it would be better to do the verification before "handing the settings to the main program". It is a very common mistake to try to handle invalid state/configuration when in fact it is mostly better and more robust to let the application/process fail immediately. But I have no idea if this applies to your situation here, it was just a hunch. :)